# How do I perform pattern replacement in command line in which I find patterns in one vector and replace from same position in other vector?

Tags: language-agnostic

So say I have two character vector lists in .txt docs, in which one has the patterns to be replaced, and the other has their replacements in the same position. For example:

```
Pattern.txt
this
is
the
pattern
```

```
Replacement.txt
these
are
our
replacements
```

And if I had a file, specifically a gff in my case, all instances of "this" would be replaced with "these", and so on. Is there a way I can use grep or a similar tool to recursively check for any instances of each pattern and replace with the corresponding replacement? I apologize if this is a repeat, I googled around and couldn't find what I needed.

Comment: note how `is` is a substring of `this`. you'll need to process the bigger words in your list first. Would be much easier if it was all in one file, i.e. `this<TAB>these` etc. Convert that to `sed 's/this/these/;s/is/are/;....;' file` . Good luck.

Comment: 1) Are these to be replaced as _words_, or as patterns wherever they are found, so in other words as well?  (Does `is` have to be a word or is it replaced in `this`?)  2) What do you mean by "_recursively_"?

Comment: If the pattern lists are longer than just a few pattern-replacement pairs, and the file to be processed fits conveniently into memory, I would store all replacement actions in memory, and tokenize the file into words, and then loop over the words and apply the replacement process, before writing out the new text.

Comment: Define also what you mean by _pattern_? Just a word (i.e. sequence of characters), or a regular expression, or....?

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `bash`, `GNU sed`, and `paste`, assuming that the files don't contain special characters which have special meaning in regular expressions and in `sed`:

```
sed -f <(paste Pattern.txt Replacement.txt |
        sed 's%^%s/\\b%; s%\t%\\b/%; s%$%/g%') file.gff
```

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately`Pattern.txt` contains `.`...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I think `Pattern.txt` is the filename, not a line in the file content, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Oh! Maybe, the formatting is ambiguous and it could be that the first item in each list is not an item but a filename. This question should definitely be edited by the OP.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Agreed. If the file really contains `.` then `s/[.]/\\&/g` could be added to the `sed` expression.

Answer (score 1):

One way, using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ cat l1
Pattern.txt
this
is
the
pattern

$ cat l2
Replacement.txt
these
are
our
replacements

$ awk '
    NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}
    {b[FNR]=$1}
    END{for (i in a) { c++; print "sed \047s/\\b" a[c] "\\b/" b[c] "/\047 file"}}
' l1 l2
```

##### Output

```
sed -E 's/\bPattern.txt\b/Replacement.txt/' file
sed -E 's/\bthis\b/these/' file
sed -E 's/\bis\b/are/' file
sed -E 's/\bthe\b/our/' file
sed -E 's/\bpattern\b/replacements/' file
```

You can pipe it to `bash` of `sh`

Comment: `\bPattern.txt\b` will match word `Pattern.txt` but also `Patternotxt`, `Pattern;txt`, `Pattern txt`...

Comment: Yes, this can be adapted by OP, I've done the most work

Answer (score 1):

In the following we call **space** a space, TAB, newline, carriage return, formfeed or vertical tab. We call **token** a contiguous string of non-**space** characters between a **space** on the left (or the beginning of a line), and a **space** on the right (or the end of a line). In line:

```
Pattern.txt   #fo!o  $ba&r@    1234
```

there are 4 **tokens**.

Let us assume, as your example suggests:

- That what you call "*patterns*" are **tokens** to compare for **equality** with **tokens** in your input `gff` file.
- That these **tokens** are stored in a file named `patterns.txt`, one per line.
- That you have **exactly as many** replacement strings as you have **tokens** to replace, stored in a file name `replacements.txt`, one per line.
- That "*recursively*" means "*iteratively*".

The following GNU `awk` script may do what you want:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {p[n++] = $0; next} NR <= 2*n {r[m++] = $0; next} {
  split($0, a, /\s+/, s)
  for(i in a) {
    for(j in p) if(a[i] == p[j]) { a[i] = r[j]; break }
    printf("%s%s", a[i], s[i])
  }
  print ""
}' patterns.txt replacements.txt file.gff
```

Explanations:

- `NR == FNR {p[n++] = $0; next}` applies only to the first listed file argument (`patterns.txt`). It populates array `p` with the **tokens** to replace and sets variable `n` to their number.
- `NR <= 2*n {r[m++] = $0; next}` does the same with the second file argument (`replacements.txt`) and stores the replacement strings in array `r`.
- The last `{...}` block processes the input file to filter (`file.gff`):

  - `split($0, a, /\s+/, s)` splits the current line in **tokens** separated by **spaces**, stores the **tokens** in array `a` and the separators in array `s`.
  - `for(i in a) {...}` loops over all **tokens** of the current line.
  - `for(j in p) if(a[i] == p[j]) { a[i] = r[j]; break }` compares the current **token** `a[i]` of the current line with each **token** in `p`. If they are equal `a[i]` is replaced by the corresponding replacement string (`r[j]`) and the search stops (`break`) to avoid a subsequent replacement if some of your replacement strings contain some of your "*patterns*".
  - `printf("%s%s", a[i], s[i])` prints the (potentially replaced) **token**, followed by the corresponding separator.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to read the reference files and form a hash (dictionary) of pattern-replacement pairs, then read the main file and run the replacements. The file can be read at once and processed whole for each pattern, or processed line by line for all patterns.  Both are done in Perl in this post.

I assume that one replaces *words*, not patterns inside other words.  (So `our` has to be a separate word to get replaced, not as a pattern in `your`.)  Then we need to check whole words (so the pattern `our` in the word `your` doesn't match).  The code below runs by that.

But if the patterns need be replaced inside other words as well, then  I'd assume that one wants to replace longer ones first (so that `our` doesn't steal it from `your`). Then we'd need to first sort sought patterns by length (so that `your` gets checked before `our`), as shown in a footnote.

There are still questions, as a replaced word can itself get replaced (what seems to be desired but I'm not sure).  I suggest to always articulate full requirements, even when all appears clear.

If the file is small enough we can "slurp" it into a string and go through patterns for replacement, one at a time for the whole file

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my %repl;    
my @pat = path("patt.txt")->lines({chomp=>1}); 
@repl{@pat} = path("repl.txt")->lines({chomp=>1}); 

my $file_content = path($file)->slurp;

for my $k (keys %repl) { 

    my $num_replaced = $file_content =~ s/\b$k\b/$repl{$k}/g;

    say "Replaced '$k' at $num_replaced places" if $num_replaced;
}

say $file_content;  # changed content
```

If my assumption that only words get replaced turns out incorrect then the regex shoudn't have the word boundary (`\b`), so to allow patterns to be matched and replaced inside words.  Then if one wants to replace longer patterns first we need to search for length-sorted patterns.<sup>†</sup>

Another way is to read the file line by line and for each line go through all replacements

```perl
# Same up to reading the file

my %num_repl;  # collect some stats

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) { 
    for my $k (@key_search_order) { 
        my $n = s/\b$k\b/$repl{$k}/g;

        $num_repl{$k} += $n if $n;
    }
    print;
}

say "Replaced '$_' at $num_repl{$_} places" for keys %num_repl;
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  With everything else being the same

```perl
my @key_search_order = 
    map { $_->[0] } 
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
    map { [$_, length] } 
        keys %repl; 

for my $k (@key_search_order) { 
    my $num_replaced = $file_content =~ s/$k/$repl{$k}/g;

    say "Replaced '$k' at $num_replaced places" if $num_replaced;
}
```

Comment: You should maybe specify which language you use...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet  When I answered the question this was the only tagged language ... (then they changed it to "language agnostic", even as the OP asked for a specific one by tagging it).  One the other hand, if the reader cannot even recognize the language... But thank you, I will add that when I edit